# Copy command has stopped working after merging batch files

Tags: batch-file

I inherited a set of batch files.
*Bat1* called *bat2* which called *bat3*.
*Bat3* created an xml, which *bat2* used to create an html and *bat1* used that to create a pdf.
Finally *bat1* copied the pdf to an output directory.

I've recently joined the three batch files into one and everything works exactly the same up to the final copy command, which fails stating the pdf cannot be found.

```
@echo off

pushd %~dp0

set sourceFile=%1
set xslt=%2
set outputFile=%3

for %%i in (%sourceFile%) do (
    set documentName=%%~ni
)

::BATCH FILE 2 CALLED
::BATCH FILE 3 CALLED

echo Processing source file compose
java -cp lib\saxon9.jar; net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:%sourceFile% -xsl:conversion\compose.xsl -o:compose.xml

echo Processing source file catalog
java -cp lib\saxon9.jar; -s:compose.xml -xsl:conversion\catalog.xsl -o:catalog.xml

::END OF BATCH FILE 3 

echo Processing source file to HTML
java -cp lib\saxon9.jar; net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:catalog.xml -xsl:conversion\html5.xsl -o:index.html

echo Bundling publication
mkdir %documentName%
xcopy /y "conversion\webapp\*" %documentName%\ /o /x /e /h /k 
move index.html %documentName%\
copy source graphics into web application img res dir
for %%f in ("*.jpg" "*.png" "*.gif" "*.svg" "*.psd" "*.ai" "*.pdf") do copy "%%f" %documentName%\asset\img\

::END OF BATCH FILE 2

echo Running AHF
AHFCmd -extlevel 4 -d %documentName%\index.html -o %documentName%.pdf -f HTML -x 4 -i tool\AHF\AHFSettings(x64).xml -stdout

::EVERYTHING WORKS FINE TO HERE; %documentName%.pdf is created just as it was previously. 

echo Moving %documentName%.pdf
copy %documentName%.pdf %outputFile%    ::Error - The system cannot find the file specified.
popd
```

The line `copy %documentName%.pdf %outputFile%` hasn't changed. I have tried using CALL in front of the AHFCmd and JAVA commands but that makes no difference. I have tried `dir /b /a-d` just before the copy command and it lists the file I want to move in the current directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run `echo %documentName%.pdf %outputFile%` right before the copy command to ensure that not only is `%outputFile%` set, but that neither `%documentName%` nor `%outputFile%` contain spaces. If either of them do, you'll have to use double quotes.

Comment: @SomethingDark, this worked... I had tried `echo %documentName%.pdf %outputFile%` before and there are no spaces in either `%outputFile%` or `%documentName%`, so didn't try double quotes. 

But putting double quotes around `%outputFile%` (even though it has no spaces in the file name) fixed the issue. Any idea why?

Comment: So there seem to be other special characters like `,`, `;`, `=` or `)`, `&`, `^`,…

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help carefully from top of first to bottom of last page. There is explained on last page with last paragraph that a file (or folder) name (or any other argument string) containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` (and also the redirection operators `<|>` to interpret as literal characters in an argument string) must be enclosed in double quotes. Well, `[` and `]` have no special meaning anymore.

Comment: @aschipfl, @Mofi, thanks! There's a `+` used as a separator in the output filenames which is causing the problems. I didn't realize it was a special character in Batch files.

Comment: You're welcome! The `+`-sign is special for the [`copy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html), which allows to merge multiple files to one…